# How to get website (EarthTV) live streams into Discord js bot?

Tags: javascript, html, discord.js

So, imagine I want my users to make a command like `!earthview <locationname>`, how can I make my bot search up for the live cams on their website and pass it to a javascript function?

Example of live cam: https://www.earthtv.com/en/webcam/rio-de-janeiro-copacabana?utm_campaign=promotion&utm_medium=horizontal&utm_source=http%3A%2F%2Fhttps.earthtv.com%2Fen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With most services, you would use an api to search for something on a website, but because there is no api for earthtv.com, you really only have one option, a website scraper. Scrapers get the html of a page, and then you have to manually parse the html into the different results. Here is some info on scraping:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/web-scraping-with-node-js-c93dcf76fe2b

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped a lot!